# Dropping rows in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am iterating through a data frame in Pandas one row at a time. I am checking whether that row meets a certain set of conditions or not. Then, I'd like to discard the row. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your criteria for whether to keep it, an easy way is to create a test function:

```
In [11]: def keep_row(row):
             return True  # you may want to make this stricter...

In [12]: df.apply(keep_row, axis=1)
```

Then you can keep only those good rows:

```
In [13]: df = df[df.apply(keep_row, axis=1)]
```

*It might be faster if you can work out some way to vectorize (use numpy to describe) the condition to keep the row, but it's hard to suggest how without a specific example.*

Comment: Is there a way I can pass in the values I want in the function? Say that I have a data frame with columns A, B, and C, and I want to use a function that uses two columns, A and B.

Comment: Edit you original question to include the example you have in mind. Bonus points for including sample data and your expected output. The answer to your question is yes, but it's much harder to explain without an example.

Comment: @user1867185 yes, just grab them using row['A'], row['B'] etc. inside the function

Answer (score 1):

First rule of pandas is that if you are iterating through the rows you are probably doing it wrong. To delete rows meeting a criteria just select the ones that don't meet the criteria e.g. of you want to remove rows with column A == "rrr":

```
df = df[df.A!="rrr"]
```